# How do I reload all the dependencies from mavenLocal using gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have Project A and B in my system and B uses some of the packages defined in A and I have added some classes in project A but i am not able to reference them in B.

What I have tried

1. Did ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal in project A
2. Did ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies

Can some please advise me how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did step 2 in project B, it should work (although I would like do a `clean` as well): `./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies`

If you do this a lot (and esp if you find it tedious to type `--refresh-dependencies` every time, you could consider marking the dependency from project A as `changing`...

```
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "seconds" }
dependencies {
    implementation("com.example.group:my-artifact:3.2.1")) { changing = true }
// ...
}
```

The `configurations` block tells Gradle how to handle changing modules, and the the `changing = true` will flag individual dependencies.  Then, every Gradle build, it will try to update the dependency.

Comment: Actually this got resolved. After step 1, I did clean and reload the workspace in vscode. I believe extension has done these steps underneath. Thanks for the reply though